# Can't serve dynamic Web Content with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

Based on a Spring Boot [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) to served dynamic web content, I wanted to do the same in Kotlin. My Kotlin project is based on this [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin). I've no issue running the code of both tutorials.

From my understanding, I only needed to add a controller that would return a reference to a template.

Here `HelloController.kt` (located under src/main/kotlin/foo/controller) :

```
package foo.controller

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

@Controller
class HelloController {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController::class.java)

    @RequestMapping("/")
    fun hello(): String {
        log.info("foo")
        return "index"
    }
}
```

Here is the simple "template", `index.html` that I want to access (located under  src/main/resources/templates/index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Bar
</body>
</html>
```

So technically, if I go to `localhost:8080` I should have `index.html` displayed which I don't. Instead I have a 404 error. I do have the logged displayed so the `hello`method is called. What am I doing wrong? I didn't see any configuration file in the Spring Boot tutorial so I guess Spring is doing something under the hood to get the correct ressource from what a function returns.

EDIT:

Has requested my graddle imports:

```
buildscript {
    val springBootVersion = "1.4.3.RELEASE"
    val kotlinVersion = "1.0.6"
    extra["kotlinVersion"] = kotlinVersion

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
    plugin("kotlin-spring")
    plugin("kotlin-jpa")
    plugin("org.springframework.boot")
}

version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    setSourceCompatibility(1.8)
    setTargetCompatibility(1.8)
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val kotlinVersion = extra["kotlinVersion"] as String

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.1")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Comment: Post here your gradle/maven dependencies.

Comment: I've added the whole file incase the issue comes from someting not so obvious (and I'm completly new to graddle too :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency is not enough to setup view resolving. Try to add `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency and **Thymeleaf** should handle your html file.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

Your HTML files should be in `src/main/resources/templates` or they might not be automatically detected.

Comment: Indeed that was as simple as that! I added the depedency and it worked just fine. Many thanks!